# SpringBoot 2.7.2 Springfox version compatibility

Tags: java, spring-boot, springfox

I am using SpringBoot 2.7.2 in my project. And using springfox version 3.0.0 for swagger documentation.

The exception thrown is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException.
What is the solution for it? Please assist.

Comment: Include the stacktrace and relevant code/configuration.

Answer (score 0):

spring fox behaves like a stranger in the new version of spring boot. you can try [spring doc openapi](https://springdoc.org/)
it works fine with spring boot 2.7.*.